# How to update SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for stupid question, but how can I update SQL column with next values.

For e.g., I have a query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Date,1,4) AS My_Year FROM Ukrtelecom.dbo.IntCalls
```

And I have column in current table named Call_Year how can I insert all data from variable/alias/substring My_Year to real column Call_Year?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to update existing rows in `IntCalls` or add new rows?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
UPDATE IntCalls
SET Call_Year = Substring([Date],1,4)
WHERE 'some condition'
```

Answer (score 0):

I considered your "Date" field is actually the date type. If it really is the date type you can not do substring, to do that you need to convert to string before.

Following SQL:

```
UPDATE IntCalls SET Call_Year = YEAR([Date]);
```

Look at my fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32ce4/6